# While Nested Loops

Tags: java

I am really struggling to solve this algorithm. I know I have to do nested loop but I

can't get around how to solve it.

Basically you have j^a,k^b,l^c,m^d, where each of a, b,  c,and d is one of the 17

numbers {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, -1/2, -1/3, -1/4, 0 or same numbers but positive}.

Now I am going to ask the user for approximation value (let's say u) and then ask him

for 4 numbers. I need to find a combination of these numbers that would satisfy the

equation: j^a*k^b*l^c*m^d where it is within 0.01 of u. For example somebody chose

238900 for approximation then chose 14,102329,1936,13 as his 4 values then the program

would check every combination (i.e.14^-5*102329^-5*..etc) to find the  closest

value to 238900 within  1%. The answer is 14^-5*102329^1*1936^1/2*13^4 which gives

you about 239103 (Sometimes you can't really get close to within 1% of value of u).

I am just struggling to put the nested loop so it checks every possible combination at

the same time instead of checking it one at a time. Assume the variables are

declared (a,b,c,d,j,k,l,m)a s a double and q as an int:

```
double [] numbers = {-5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0/2.0, -1.0/3.0, -1.0/4.0, 0.0, 1.0/4.0, 1.0/3.0, 1.0/2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}

while(j - u < k){
    while(k - u < l){
        while(l - u < m){
            while(m < u * 0.01){
                Math.pow(m,numbers[q];
                q++;
            }
            int i = 0;
            if(i == 0){
                q = 0;
                i++;
            }
            Math.pow(l,numbers[q]);
            q++;
        }
        int y = 0;
        if(y == 0){
            q = 0;
            y++;
        }
        Math.pow(k,numbers[q]);
        q++;
    }
    int r = 0;
    if (r == 0){
       q = 0;
       r++
    }
    Math.pow(j,numbers[q]);
    q++;
}
```

Comment: Is it machine language ??I'm unable to read it.

Comment: I don't like seeing numbers and equations like this. Post some code.

Comment: try to put your approach to the solution and what have you try.

Comment: There are only 17^4 different possible choices for the indices.  That's easily enumerable. Make an array of the index values, and then have four nested `for` loops go over the array. Keep track of the closest answer. Job done.

Comment: Thank you for the format editing -- the question is easier to read. Please see the notes under the 'put on hold' message. You either need to post some code, or outline the problem in way that makes it of value to everyone else.

Comment: Why have you edited back in the impossible to read blank line text?

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé How do you enumerate through the for loops that's what I can't figure out.!!

Comment: @KennethFaried How have you been faring? Were you able to follow the code posted?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I would try to modify your code so you can learn where you were going wrong, but I don't think that is feasible in this case.  I will point out a few things you might want to look at, and then provide a implementation that fits your provided constraints.

Things to look at in your code:

1. The objective `u` appears in each of your loops, e.g. `while (j - u < k)`.  That doesn't make sense because you are trying to compute something *other* than the objective, and the compare the two.
2. The constraints did not mention that indices should be related in any way.  Thus mentioning `j` and `k` in the same condition seems strange.
3. The calls to Math.pow compute a result which is subsequently discarded.

Below is a short program that does what you described.  It produces the following output for your test data:

```
14.000000^-5.000000 * 102329.000000^1.000000 * 1936.000000^0.500000 * 13.000000^4.000000 = 239102.786480 (approx 238900.000000)
```

The program is given below.  Feel free to examine it closely, and adapt it if your problem changes.

```
public class Indices
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double j = 14.0;
        double k = 102329.0;
        double l = 1936.0;
        double m = 13.0;

        double u = 238900.0;

        double[] r = new Indices().findIndices(j, k, l, m, u);

        if (r == null)
            System.out.println("No solution");
        else
            System.out.format("%f^%f * %f^%f * %f^%f * %f^%f = %f (approx %f)%n", j, r[0], k, r[1], l, r[2], m, r[3], r[4], u);
    }

    double[] findIndices(double j, double k, double l, double m, double u)
    {
        // constants
        double[] indices = new double[] { -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, -1.0/2.0, -1.0/3.0, -1.0/4.0, 0.0, 1.0/4.0, 1.0/3.0, 1.0/2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };

        double threshold = u * 0.01; // initially 1% of objective value

        double[] bestIndices = null; // initially unknown
        double bestDelta = threshold + 1;

        for (int ai = 0; ai < indices.length; ai++)
        {
            double p1 = Math.pow(j, indices[ai]);

            for (int bi = 0; bi < indices.length; bi++)
            {
                double p2 = p1 * Math.pow(k, indices[bi]);

                for (int ci = 0; ci < indices.length; ci++)
                {
                    double p3 = p2 * Math.pow(l, indices[ci]);

                    for (int di = 0; di < indices.length; di++)
                    {
                        double p4 = p3 * Math.pow(m, indices[di]);

                        double delta = Math.abs(p4 - u);
                        if (delta < bestDelta)
                        {
                            // record new best
                            bestDelta = delta;
                            bestIndices = new double[]
                                {
                                    indices[ai],
                                    indices[bi],
                                    indices[ci],
                                    indices[di],
                                    p4
                                };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bestIndices;
    }
}
```